# Is a B-Tree a specialization of a Heap

Tags: heap, b-tree, abstract-data-type

I am not completely certain, but looking at the operations it seems a Heap is a more specific form of a self-balancing search tree that just focuses on extracting minimum and maximum

Answer (score 3):

A binary heap is a specialized form of a binary tree. It's not typically used for searching, but rather for being able to quickly return the smallest (or largest, depending on how you structure it) item in the container. A binary heap is not a good structure for searching.

A binary heap doesn't have much in common with a [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

There are many other types of heaps: skew heap, pairing heap, Fibonacci heap, etc. These, too, are typically tree structures, but again are not used for searching and have little in common with a B-Tree.

Comment: I learned that a Priority Queue is actually the corresponding abstract data type to what I was looking for, a Heap is an efficient implementation of that.